# ASP.NET GridView in edit mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a Gridview, that places two image icons for selecting and deleting a specific row. The grid is bound to a jquery datatable, but when I select the image to select the row, the default behaviour is to force a post back, which then causes the grid to loose the datable settings.

Any idea how I retain the datatable on click of either button?

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdMessageDups" runat="server" DataSourceID="sourceDuplicates"
     AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Image"
             SelectImageUrl="~/images/icn_alert_success.png"/>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" 
             ImageUrl="~/images/icn_alert_error.png" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MsgDateDetailDuplicatesID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="1" HeaderText="Heading 1" />
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="2" HeaderText="Heading 2" />
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="3" HeaderText="Heading 3" />
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Then the DataTable JQuery stuff is:

```
                var oTable = $('#grdMessageDetail').dataTable({
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "ALL"]],
                'asStripClasses': null,
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": false,
                "sDom": 'RC<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',

                //Scrolling .......
                "sScrollY": "250px",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "100%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                });
```

The code in the code behind is:

```
public static void MakeAccessible(GridView grid)
{
    if (grid.Rows.Count <= 0) return;
    grid.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
    grid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    if (grid.ShowFooter)
        grid.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
}
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    MakeAccessible(grdMessageDups);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by **bound to a jquery datatable** ? are you initializing gridview to behave as jquery datatable ?

Comment: Yes - so i build the Gridview using code behind, then when the DOM is loaded and the Pre_Init has handeled the information, the datatable is added to the Grid. When i click on the button, is causes a postback. However, I can't seem to cancel this calling a JQuery Function, that stops the defaultbehaviour

Comment: are you calling jquery datatable initialization script on $(document).ready(function() {
//Your Script
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from all the final solution was:

```
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                       <a href="#" id="selectImage">
                        <img src="images/icn_alert_success.png" /></a>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
```

then this JQuery Code:

```
                  $('[id$=selectImage]').click(function (evt) {
                  evt.preventDefault();
                 alert("item selected");
                  });
```

So, now, i need to perform obtaining the KeyValue for the row selected and we are golden.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bound it every time an event occurs on the grid..

Answer (score 0):

What are doing to select a row is is a client side event (java-script or jQuery) in both cases use

```
return false;
```

if any function is being called onclick in (java-script or jQuery)

### Edit

You can replace

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" 
         ImageUrl="~/images/icn_alert_error.png" />
```

with template filed and put image instead image button there as follow

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <img src="~/images/icn_alert_error.png" />    
       </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: The Grid is being populated using standard ASP.NET grid methods, so i have a CommandField for the image, i want to intercept this click event, then use JQuery to take over the action.

Comment: buttonfield i guess. on click of this button, i want to use JQuery to e.PreventDefaults()

Comment: do you have any jquery function written on that `ButtonField`?

Comment: Shekhar - i'd totally forgotten about the ItemTemplate stuff :-)